# How to solve the the Curl's "Couldn't connect to server"

Tags: ruby, curl, rspec, capybara, webmock

I'm using Rspec with Capybara with WebMock for my tests (also I'm using Charles proxy), Getting the following error, never in a specific test.

I've had this happen once in a while, using rspec-retry mostly to deal with it, but now I've noticed it take allot of time on each encounter with this error.

Any ideas?

```
    Curl::Err::ConnectionFailedError: Couldn't connect to server
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/curb-0.8.8/lib/curl/easy.rb:72:in `perform'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/curb-0.8.8/lib/curl/easy.rb:294:in `http'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/curb-0.8.8/lib/curl/easy.rb:294:in `http_get'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/curb.rb:63:in `request'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `isElementDisplayed'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:190:in `displayed?'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb:126:in `visible?'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:252:in `block in visible?'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:252:in `visible?'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/queries/selector_query.rb:49:in `matches_filters?'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/result.rb:28:in `block in initialize'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/result.rb:28:in `select'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/result.rb:28:in `initialize'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/queries/selector_query.rb:120:in `new'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/queries/selector_query.rb:120:in `block in resolve_for'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/queries/selector_query.rb:108:in `resolve_for'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:125:in `block in assert_selector'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:124:in `assert_selector'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:40:in `has_selector?'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:271:in `has_css?'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:699:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
    ./spec/charts/charts_dialog_spec.rb:203:in `block in simple_chart_breakdown_initial'
    ./spec/charts/charts_dialog_spec.rb:201:in `times'
    ./spec/charts/charts_dialog_spec.rb:201:in `simple_chart_breakdown_initial'
    ./spec/charts/charts_dialog_spec.rb:1113:in `block (7 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.5/lib/rspec/retry.rb:98:in `block in run'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.5/lib/rspec/retry.rb:88:in `loop'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.5/lib/rspec/retry.rb:88:in `run'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.5/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in `run_with_retry'
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.5/lib/rspec/retry.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
    -e:1:in `load'
    -e:1:in `<main>'
```

origianl Gemfile.lock:

```
    GEM
    remote: https://rubygems.org/
    specs:
    activesupport (4.2.5)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    archive-zip (0.7.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    backports (3.6.8)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capybara (2.7.1)
      addressable
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    childprocess (0.5.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (1.0.0)
      archive-zip (~> 0.7.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
    ci_reporter (2.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    ci_reporter_rspec (1.0.0)
      ci_reporter (~> 2.0)
      rspec (>= 2.14, < 4)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    crack (0.4.3)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    curb (0.8.8)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.9.14)
    ffi (1.9.14-x64-mingw32)
    hashdiff (0.2.3)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    interception (0.5)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.8.3)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    nokogiri (1.6.8-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    parallel (1.6.1)
    parallel_tests (2.2.1)
      parallel
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    pry (0.10.3)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-rescue (1.4.2)
      interception (>= 0.5)
      pry
    pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7)
      pry (>= 0.9.11)
    puma (2.15.3)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rspec (3.4.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-core (3.4.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.4.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
    rspec-retry (0.4.5)
      rspec-core
    rspec-support (3.4.1)
    rubyzip (1.2.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    selenium-webdriver (2.53.4)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0)
    sinatra (1.4.7)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    sinatra-contrib (1.4.7)
      backports (>= 2.0)
      multi_json
      rack-protection
      rack-test
      sinatra (~> 1.4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slop (3.6.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    webmock (1.22.3)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
      hashdiff
    websocket (1.2.3)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

    PLATFORMS
    ruby
    x64-mingw32

    DEPENDENCIES
    capybara
    chromedriver-helper
    ci_reporter_rspec
    curb
    factory_girl
    parallel_tests
    pry-rescue
    pry-stack_explorer
    puma
    rake
    rspec
    rspec-retry
    selenium-webdriver
    sinatra
    sinatra-contrib
    webmock

    BUNDLED WITH
    1.11.2
```

diff of new Gemfile, still "Couldn't connect to server" error:

```
    capybara (2.14.0)
    rspec (>= 2.2.0, < 4)
    selenium-webdriver (3.4.0)
```

Comment: Thats a failure of selenium to communicate with the browser (I assume firefox 47 since you're still on selenium-webdriver 2.53.4?) for control. Are you running that connection through your proxy? All of your gems are really old versions, do you need to stay on those versions?

Comment: Using Chrome, I will update them tomorrow, post the Gemfile.lock before and after, and the results, thanks :)

Comment: If you're using Chrome, definitely update your gems and make sure you update chromedriver as well

Comment: using Chrome: Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

Comment: That's over a year old too - so unless you have a good reason for staying on that you should probably just update everything.  If you need to stay on Chrome 49 use the latest chromedriver that works with that version

Comment: updated chromedriver + chrome, seems to solve it :)